# Get value from IEnumerable foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I need to create a c# object from a JSON file, and have to following working solution:

JSON:

```
{
"AK": {
    "Anchorage": [{
        "Name": "John Doe",
        "Address": "123 Main St.",
        "City": "Anchorage",
        "State": "AK",
        "Zip": "12345"
    }],
    "Fairbanks": [{
        "Name": "Sally Smith",
        "Address": "987 Main St.",
        "City": "Fairbanks",
        "State": "AK",
        "Zip": "98765"
    }]
}
}
```

Code:

```
public class Location
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------
string json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:json.txt");
dynamic deserialisedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

var locations = new List<Location>();

foreach (var root in deserialisedJson)
{
    foreach (var state in root)
    {
        foreach (var city in state)
        {
            foreach (var location in city)
            {
                Location loc = new Location();
                loc.Name = location.First["Name"];
                loc.Address = location.First["Address"];
                loc.City = location.First["City"];
                loc.State = location.First["State"];
                loc.Zip = location.First["Zip"];
                locations.Add(loc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I need to incorporate the above into an SSIS package, which only allows .NET 3.5 and below. The line of code below requires .NET 4.0 and above:

```
dynamic deserialisedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

I'm trying to workaround this limitation by using IEnumerable, but I'm not sure of the syntax of how to grab the values I need?

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(@"C:json.txt");

var deserialisedJson = (IEnumerable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

var locations = new List<Location>();

foreach (var root in deserialisedJson)
{
    foreach (var state in (IEnumerable)root)
    {
        foreach (var city in (IEnumerable)state)
        {
            foreach (var location in (IEnumerable)city)
            {
                Location loc = new Location();

                loc.Name = //What goes here???
                loc.Address = //What goes here???
                loc.City = //What goes here???
                loc.State = //What goes here???
                loc.Zip = //What goes here???

                locations.Add(loc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: location["Name"] ?

Comment: add a small json example

Comment: using `location["Name"] ` gives an error: `cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'`

Comment: instead of `dynamic deserialisedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);` is `ClassThatHasJsonStructure deserialisedJson = Json.Decode<ClassThatHasJsonStructure>(json)` working in .Net3.5?

Comment: You don't really need a type. you can deserialize it in a "dynamic" way. But we need the structure of the json.

Comment: a  small JSON snippet is included at the top of the post.

Comment: should look up the document and try to deserialize it as Dictionary<string, object>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses [Linq to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) to select all the `Location` objects you want:

```
var deserialisedJson = (IEnumerable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(json);

//Get all tokens that are under AK/(some descendant)/all items from collection
var result = jObj.SelectTokens("AK.*.[*]")
                    .Select(x => new Location
                    {
                        Name = x["Name"].Value<string>(),
                        Address = x["Address"].Value<string>(),
                        City = x["City"].Value<string>(),
                        State = x["State"].Value<string>(),
                        Zip = x["Zip"].Value<string>(),
                    }).ToList();
```

*Tested and this works in a .Net 3.5 project with a `Newtonsoft.Json` package suitable for the .Net*

Comment: @PixelPaul - did this help you?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick solution:

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
var locations = (
    from state in deserialized.Properties().Select(v => v.Value).OfType<JObject>()
    from city in state.Properties().Select(v => v.Value).OfType<JArray>()
    from location in city
    select new Location
    {
        Name = location.Value<string>("Name"),
        Address = location.Value<string>("Address"),
        City = location.Value<string>("City"),
        State = location.Value<string>("State"),
        Zip = location.Value<string>("Zip")
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the clases to let newtonsoft resolve what you need

```
public class Location
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
}
public class AK
{
    public Location[] Anchorage { get; set; }
    public Location[] Fairbanks { get; set; }
}   


var ak = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AK>(json);
```

Comment: If you need them in the same list just concat them and that's all.
var locations = ak.Anchorage.Concat(ak.Fairbanks);